# How to customize the width and height when show an Activity as a Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

If I have defined a Activity:

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(dialog_activity.xml);
    }


}
```

I would like to display the above activity like a dialog, so in the ***AndroidManifest.xml*** file, I declare this activity like below:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Everything is fine at this point, my `DialogActivity` showed as a dialog.

The problem is How to customize the width and height of the `DialogActivity` to make it more like a small dialog? (Currently it occupies most of the screen by default)

**----------------------------Update-----------------------**

I defined a custom theme like below:

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

        <item name="android:width">100dip</item> 
        <item name="android:height">100dip</item>

</style>
```

Then, declare the `DialogActivity` in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** as.

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity" android:theme="@style/myDialog"/>
```

My `DialogActivity` now even occupies the whole screen:( . The **width** and **height** definition:

```
<item name="android:width">100dip</item>
```

in the theme do not take any effect, why?

Comment: try width & height as "wrap_content". Add some margin as well.

Comment: Incorrect namespace. Try this,<style name="myDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

Comment: @ chedine , that's my typo. I did what you suggested,but not help the problem

Comment: Try setting the theme in your activity. before your super.onCreate();YourActivity.setTheme(R.style.myDialog) and remove the theme option from manifest.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I finally figured out one way to customize the size of my `DialogActivity`.

That's inside the `onCreate()` method of `DialogActivity`, add the following code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
params.x = -20;  
params.height = 100;  
params.width = 550;  
params.y = -10;  

this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: The borders of my modified activity are black. Is there a way to make them semi-transparent?

Comment: this will not work since at that time width could be 0. You should use addOnGlobalLayoutListener and put above logic into it.

Comment: **this.getWindow().setAttributes(params); ** must be after setContentView(int res).

Comment: can anyone please tell me what params.x and params.y attributes actually do?

Comment: yes this works for me but around the resized activity the space/borders are black how do i remove the borders?

Comment: Is there a way to do it cleanly in the XML but not in the code?

Answer (score 4):

You can just change params of window in your acctivity like:

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, I used following theme for my activity

```
android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

The following code fixed my problem

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
 getWindow().setLayout(width(pixels),height(pixels));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layout height and width in layout xml file

You can even mention the values like "240px" for android:layout_width/android:layout_height

Answer (score 0):

There's a one-line code without hassling with the LayoutParams that is

```
getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.25));
```

This is what I've used before in one of my projects and now searching for, but found it in the same project.